# Call WCF service asynchronously from Web API

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, web

How could I call call WCF Service asychronously from asp.net Web API.

I do not want to use asyc and await keywork with my Web API function.

Is there any other way to implement same solutions.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `async` and `await`?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200381/asp-net-mvc-4-application-calling-remote-webapi

Comment: my application configured with .NET 4.0 so I can't use this keyword in application. also I want to generate async request from web api to web service and want to communicate wcf response to java script client through web api

Answer (score 0):

when you add the service reference you can enable code generation for Asyncronous operations which will give you BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods for every method exposed via service so that u can call them asynchronously

[image]