# retrieving data from web api , into MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How am I retrieving data from my Web api , into my MVC application ?

I've got a simple CRUD web api that have a `GetItem`  method.

here it is :

```
 // GET api/UserAwesome/5
    public Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return item;
    }
```

When I run in my browser `http://localhost:32120/api/UserAwesome/1`, everything is fine and cool, I get the information ..

but how am I retrieve it in my MVC application ?

I've got this `ActionResult` :

```
    public ActionResult UserDetails(int userId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

what should I place there?

Comment: Do you mean how to display on a view?

Comment: no, I mean how do I get the data into my controller first..

Comment: Why would you call your API from your controller? unless these are different projects?

Comment: these are different projects indeed.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200381/asp-net-mvc-4-application-calling-remote-webapi