# Asp.Net Web api communicating with another web api over REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api2

In my current architecture, I have a public facing Gateway API (asp.net Web API 2) that talks to multiple back end APIs (again Web API2) over REST for serving up requests. I know that HttpClient can be used to perform API to API communication in this scenario. But, this setup will not provide the compile time type checking and intellisense we get when using WCF over the wire or Remote Procedure Calls.

Can we achieve Type Checking and intellisense with REST using Web API2?

thank you,
Soma.

Comment: What do you mean by `compile time type checking and intellisense`? Do you mean Proxy like WSDL?

Comment: Yes like proxy client when using WCF. Thank you

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200381/asp-net-mvc-4-application-calling-remote-webapi/13207679#13207679