# What is the correct way of consuming a web api if it is separated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

```js
//controller
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(List<Music> musicList)
        {
            var x = Post.Add(musicList); <--ivegoterrorhere
            return View();
        }

//webAPI
public class MusicController : ApiController
    {

        // POST: api/Music
        public static string Post(List<Music> musicList)
        {
            
            MusicBusiness.addMusic(musicList);
            return "successful";

        }
    }
```

What is the correct way of consuming a web api if it is separated from the main web application?
My solution has two projects, webAPI and
The  web Application project is going to call the webAPI project.

Comment: use a http client to call the web api endpint

Comment: If you are really old school you can use wcf: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13207679/1157185