# How to consume python machine learning model script with asp.net-mvc application

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-mvc, machine-learning, spyder

I'm working on a asp.net application where i have to do heart disease prediction. This is done through machine learning (dataset from kaggle heart.csv). I prepared the machine learning model using PYTHON SCRIPT IN SPYDER IDE and used multiple algorithms to get accuracy of the model. Now I want to integrate this script with my asp.net mvc application in a way that data can be entered from asp.net and passed through my python script for Machine learning and get the results back in my asp.net mvc site. How is this possible please give me detailed step by step solution. Thank you. 
*below is my ML code*

https://www.kaggle.com/cdabakoglu/heart-disease-classifications-machine-learning/notebook

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way may be creating `Restful API` in `Python`, So that your `Asp.NET MVC` site can consume it easily.

Below steps may help:

**1.** Create Restful API in Python for your existing Code

May be you can use [Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) for creating the API in Python.

**2.** Pass or Post Data to Python API using .NET [HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value)

**3.** Read Python API Results using .NET [HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200381/asp-net-mvc-4-application-calling-remote-webapi)